# Invoking functions multiple times in a row

Tags: javascript

I'm curious why:

```
(function () { return 'one' })()()
```

returns:

```
TypeError: (intermediate value)(...) is not a function
```

and not:

```
TypeError: 'one' is not a function
```

Comment: Interesting question :) if you assign your function, let's say to `f`, we've got `Uncaught TypeError: f(...) is not a function`. `intermediate value` seems to come from the fact the function is anonymous but the error message is like the first call is not really evaluated already.

Comment: The function returns a string. After it is executed, the second function call would be `'one'()` which is not the same as `one()` (as you probably intend).

Answer (score 2):

Error messages use variable names or other identities to say what is not a function. Because the return value hasn't been assigned to anything, it doesn't have an identifier, so the engine says `intermediate value`

Comment: Ok, but 'one' is just a string, it's not assigned to anything eather or am i wrong?

Comment: @Src yes, it's just a string, not a variable.

Comment: And it's because it's not assigned to anything that the engine spits out `intermediate value` instead of a name

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation of the error message *"TypeError: "x" is not a function"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function) explains:

> **What went wrong?**
>
> It attempted to call a value from a function, but the value is not actually a function. Some code expects you to provide a function, but that didn't happen.

It also provides some code examples that triggers this error and the actual error message reported by them. I won't copy them here but please take a closer look on them and notice the error messages they generate.

The *"x"* part is replaced in the actual error messages by the **name of the object** that is expected to be a function and it is not.

Because the object in this case does not have a name (it is an intermediate result computed during the evaluation of the expression, see the explanation below), the engine cannot report its name and tries to be as helpful as it can. It reports *"(intermediate value)(...)"* probably because this way it is more descriptive; it is a value returned by a function that is not stored but used for computation of another value.

**It cannot report the actual value** instead because the intermediate value can be anything; if it is a complex data structure then the error message becomes bloated without adding much information.

Apparently I didn't understand the question from the first time, what follows is my initial answer that explains why the error is generated, not why the error message is what it is and not what the OP expects.

---

This code ...

```
(function () { return 'one' })()()
```

1. ... creates an anonymous function...

   ```
   function () { return 'one' }
   ```
2. ... calls it...

   ```
   (function () { return 'one' })()
   ```
3. ... then attempts to interpret the value returned by the function as another function and call it:

   ```
   (function () { return 'one' })()()
   ```

The function created on step #1 returns a string (`'one'`) when it is invoked (on step #2).

On step #3, the effect of the code is the same as calling `'one'()`. This is not the same as `one()` (as you might think).

The intermediate value referred in the error message is the string returned by the first function call that is then used in the expression (as a function) without being saved in a variable (that's the explanation of the "intermediate" wording.)

As the error message clearly says, `'one'` is not a function and attempting to use it as a function (by placing the second pair of parenthesis in the expression) doesn't work.

In order to make it work, the anonymous function created on step #1 must return another (anonymous) function, like this:

```
(function() { return function() { return 'one'; } })()()
```

Now, when it is called, the outer function returns an anonymous function that is similar with the anonymous function created on step #1 by the original code. When this function is called (the second `()`) it returns the string `'one'`.

This is probably not what you wanted. Calling a function given its name as string is possible only by using `eval()` which is language feature that is best to avoid (for several strong reasons.)

Comment: Exacly, i also thought that `On step #3, the effect of the code is the same as calling 'one'().` but it turns out that is not true. That is what my question about!

Comment: I guess I didn't understand your question from the first time. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because when in braces `()` it (`function () { return 'one' }`) becomes an **expression which yields intermediate results** and those *results are not yet bound to a variable yet*.

As per [spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-specification-types),

> Specification type values are specification artefacts that **do not
>   necessarily correspond to any specific entity** within an ECMAScript
>   implementation.
>
> Specification type values may be used to describe **intermediate results**
>   of ECMAScript expression evaluation but such values cannot be stored
>   as properties of objects or values of ECMAScript language variables.

Comment: Don't know why this got a down vote. It's a better answer than mine